# Dependency injection not working on spring boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i didn't figure out why this is not working , i am trying to implement a simple end point
this is my controller

```
@RestController
public class CustomerController {
    private final CustomerService customerService;


    @Autowired
    public CustomerController(CustomerService customerService) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    Customer getCustomer(){
        return customerService.getCustomer();
    }
}
```

and this is my service

```
@Component
public class CustomerService {
    public Customer getCustomer(){
        return new Customer("Anas",23,"Monday");
    }

}
```

when i go to localhost:8000/ i got the next error message : " This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. "

i tried to add another endpoint like this

```
 @GetMapping("/hi")
    String sayHi(){
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

and its working , i assume that getCustomer method on controller not working because the  object not injected well , what am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that's was my bad , the problem was on the Custumer Class , i should have add setters and getters for the fields